# problem occurr while display data into jsp file from servlet

Tags: database, jsp, servlets

i have fetched data from database in servlet and want to  display them into jsp  form's radio button.

employee.jsp

Employee Gender ' >Male '>Female

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow . Please share your servlet and JSP code which you tried

Comment: i am unable to add my code here can you please tell me how can i add my code here. So you can see them

Comment: Edit your question and it will open up an editor where you can post your code and it would be great if you could explain what exactly is the problem e.g are you seeing the data in Servlet OR do you see any errors in the logs etc. Make sure you post all the appropriate information and you would find a lot of help for your problem on SO.